# define partition sizes using two harddisks with two OS

Tags: linux, partitioning, samba

I bought a new computer with the harddisks. The first one is a 250GB SSD HD and the second one is a normal 2TB HD.

I would like to install windows 8.1 and linux on my computer and to have a common zone to both of them.

I would like to have a partition that windows and Linux could accuses where i could place there pictures\movies and etc.

How should i split the partitions?
Should i use SAMBA? Today Linux users can write on NTFS partitions, so is there really a need for SAMBA?

Comment: Samba is inappropriate as you are not planning on running both operating systems simultaneously.

Comment: Samba and NTFS serve different purposes. Samba (and its protocol, SMB) is for serving files over the network, not for local sharing. Furthermore, it is not possible to use Samba to share files between the two OS on the same physical machine - when Windows is booted, Samba is not running, and hence is unable to serve files. An NTFS partition can be used to share files between two operating systems. While file performance may be degraded (especially in Linux), it is a better choice than FAT32 due to the 4 GB per file limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, my solution is to boot Linux (Debian) from the SSD and run Windows in a Virtual instance using VirtualBox. I set up a large partition for /home (in your case maybe the whole 2TB HDD?) and keep the virtual W7 file in my user folder.

In the Virtualbox config for my W7 instance I set up the "/home/[user]/Documents" folder as shared with auto mounting. In this folder I also placed Thunderbird/Icedoves profile folder so I can point to this and see the same mail accounts in both Debian and W7

The only drawback so far is that I have not found a way to redirect w7 special folder "My Documents" to this share (I put a shortcut in the original "My Documents" folder instead)

OT: Any idea on that?

Comment: thank you for your answer, nether the less i would prefer to install two OS instead of VM.